# rotating/orbit multiple items on canvas api using JSON

Tags: javascript, canvas

i am working on a script that i want to rotate a bunch of items from JSON on my canvas

here is my loop:

```
    var upQuarksCount = uNACG.quark.up.count;//number of entities - uNACG.anything is the JSON lookup in my localStorage

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,cW,cH);

    for(var i = 0; i < upQuarksCount; i++) {//making a bunch of circles based on the number in localStorage
        if(uNACG.quark.up.entities[i]){//check if it actually exists
            var centerWidth = cW / 2,//half the window width
                centerHeight = cH / 2,//half the window height
                posX = uNACG.quark.up.entities[i].posX,//x position of entity
                posY = uNACG.quark.up.entities[i].posY;//y position of entity

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = "gold";
            ctx.arc(posX, posY, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);//the actual circles
            ctx.stroke();

        }else{
            console.log("no entities");
        }
    }
```

As it is, all the elements in my local storage are called and they appear where I want them to.  Now, I need them to rotate. What would be the best way to accomplish this with no rendering issues? When i tried to use translate and rotate, the whole canvas when bonkers.  It was unpleasant to watch.

Please help

edits: made comments to clarify variable meanings.

Extra Note: The code above occurs inside a game loop.  So it repeats and refreshes each time.  This makes it so that any changes in the JSON is updated with the canvas.

inside the loop i can do things like this:

```
if(uNACG.quark.up.entities[i].posX < centerWidth) {
    uNACG.quark.up.entities[i].posX++; 
}
```

Result: The entity would move to the right by a set amount each time the canvas refreshes until it reaches the center of the users window.

With conditionals, i can do some tricky stuff.  But making the entities rotate independently is proving to be difficult.  do i have to make a new animation frame for each one?

Comment: Could you please provide with some sample data eg. uNACG.quark.up or uNACG.quark.down?

Comment: i made the edits.  also i deleted the down quark, it's still in my code, but for this question i don't need it.  For this, example, i trimmed it down to just the code block for the up quarks because that's all that really matters right now.  The uNACG is coming from another library and rides in as a param, it's nothing more than the location of where each entity get's store with some extras like polarity, mass, and what not.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what uNACG.quark.up looks like? Could you send me a JSON string?

Comment: userNACG = {quark: {up: {count: 0,polarity: true,entities: {}} is what it looks like at first from library.  entities is empty until the user makes new entities and that happens on-the-fly